# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, exception, sieve-of-eratosthenes

When I run my program I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at eraKevgiri.main(eraKevgiri.java:29)
```

What is the problem with this code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int gSayi = 0;
    int kKok = (int) Math.sqrt(gSayi);
    boolean[] liste = new boolean[gSayi + 1];

    Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Sayı Girin:");
    gSayi = klavye.nextInt();

    for(int i=2; i<=kKok; i++){
        System.out.println("" +i);
        for(int j=i*i; j<=gSayi; j+=i){
            liste[j] = true;
        }
    }

    for(int k=kKok; k<=gSayi; k++){ 
        if(!liste[k]){ //-------> problem in here
            System.out.println("" + k);
        }
    }
    klavye.close();
}
```

Comment: Your array does not have the index that your are trying to access. Try adding breakpoints to your code and look at the values of your array in debug more to verify that you have the values in the array you are expecting..

Comment: just a question...quite off-topic but... does the first "for" statement does anything? Because it seems that you are cycling i=2 and  kKok wich has been set as sqrt of 0 which is 0...

Comment: @Noya yep it does. You need them for "sieve of eratosthenes" algorithm. Otherwise you can not reach the (users input) all prime numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Sayı Girin:");
gSayi = klavye.nextInt();
```

to the beginning of the method, otherwise the array will always have only one element and then of course there is no element with index 1.

Answer (score 1):

You first allocate an array of size `gSayi + 1`, which is `0 + 1 = 1`. Later, you modify `gSayi` and try to access an element of `liste`, which has just one element.

So, you must either not modify `gSayi` or adjust your array to the modified value.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing things in the wrong order. When you call:

```
boolean[] liste = new boolean[gSayi + 1];
```

You're creating an array with only one element since `gSayi + 1` is always `1` here. Move your code around like this:

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Sayı Girin:");
int gSayi = 0;
gSayi = klavye.nextInt();
int kKok = (int) Math.sqrt(gSayi);
boolean[] liste = new boolean[gSayi + 1];
```

The size of the array won't change because you update `gSayi`. Likewise with `kKok`, it won't be updated to the new square root of `gSayi`. It will use the value at that instance of time.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int k=kKok; k<=gSayi; k++)` here gSayi's value is taken from user. So if it greater than 1 then it raise a error as `boolean[] liste` size is 1.That is why `liste[k]` goes out of bound.

you should make `liste` this to dynamic, ex List.